# Processing 3.3.5 - getToolkit() does not exist

Tags: processing

im trying to change frame icon in my Processing application, but it says that getToolkit() does not exist. Am i missing a library or something?

```
frame.setIconImage( getToolkit().getImage("icon.png") );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Processing 3, `frame` got replaced by `surface` as you can see [on the Changes in 3.0 wiki page](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0#things-that-may-break-your-2x-sketches), but now it's simpler and more intuitive:

```
surface.setIcon(loadImage("YOUR_ICON_HERE.png"));
```

More `surface` details are available on the [PSurface javadocs](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PSurface.html)